# The audio file on iOS that is being played on Android does not hear me. Only sound that's not good

Tags: android, ios, swift, swift3, avfoundation

I'm working on a recorder app on iOS and a friend of mine he's doing it on Android, but when he want's to play my url sound which I send to server and which also works fine for me when I play it .. he hears a lot of noise and not my actual recorder.

```
    func setupRecorder() {

    let myID = userDefaults.value(forKey: "user_id") as! Int
    let message_token = generateUniqueToken()
    self.curentFileName = message_token
    let currentFileName = "\(String(describing: self.curentFileName!))"+"."+"\(myID).m4a"

    let documentsDirectory = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
    self.soundFileURL = documentsDirectory.appendingPathComponent(currentFileName)
    print("writing to soundfile url: '\(soundFileURL!)'")

    if FileManager.default.fileExists(atPath: soundFileURL.absoluteString) {
        print("soundfile \(soundFileURL.absoluteString) exists")
    }

    let recordSettings: [String : Any] = [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatAppleLossless,
                                          AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
                                          AVEncoderBitRateKey: 320000,
                                          AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2,
                                          AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0]

    do {
        soundRecorder = try AVAudioRecorder.init(url: soundFileURL, settings: recordSettings)
        soundRecorder.delegate = self
        soundRecorder.isMeteringEnabled = true
        soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
    }
    catch {
        soundRecorder = nil
        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
}
```

This is my recorder settings....

What I have from him it s only

```
   private static final int SAMPLE_PER_SEC = 8000;
   private static final int CHANNEL_TYPE = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
   private static final int AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;

   private static int BUFFER_ELEMENT_TO_REC = 1024; // want to play 2048 (2K) since 2 bytes we use only 1024
   private static int BYTES_PER_ELEMENT = 2;
   ENCODING_PCM_16BIT
```

He said I m encoding my sound somehow and he s doing a raw record...I have no ideea where i m messing it since it s my first time with AvFoundation

Comment: You need to match parameters with him. He is using `kAudioFormatLinearPCM`, 8000 sample rate, 1 channel and you will want to add a key to set th ebit depth to 16. You don't need a bit rate with pcm.

Comment: The kAudioFormatAppleLossless Codec is probably not supported on other platforms.  You need to pick an encoding format that his end is capable of playing.   Maybe kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC would work.

Comment: @Paulw11 .  `let recordSettings: [String : Any] = [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
                                              AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
                                              AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey: 16,
                                              AVSampleRateKey: 8000,
                                              AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 1]`

Comment: Still crashing...going to catch {
            soundRecorder = nil
            print(error.localizedDescription)
        }

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using kAudioFormatAppleLossless change that to kAudioFormatLinearPCM. kAudioFormatAppleLossless format is a format only for Apple devices. It is better to use a common format for Android and iOS
devices, so that if any processing in the server for the audio, server doesn't have to handle the audio in two different way

Comment: kAudioFormatLinearPCM it 's crashing my application... it is jumping to catch

Comment: AVEncoderAudioQualityKey: AVAudioQuality.max.rawValue,
AVEncoderBitRateKey: 320000,
AVNumberOfChannelsKey: 2, try removing these

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.)...Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value...... soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()

Comment: I've made the modifications you requested

Comment: delete the last line     soundRecorder.prepareToRecord()
and post the error your are getting here

Comment: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error 1718449215.)
Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Comment: `let recordSettings: [String : Any] = [AVFormatIDKey: kAudioFormatLinearPCM,
                                              AVSampleRateKey: 44100.0]
`